# Error: Setting up fake worker failed: "Cannot find module './pdf.worker.js' using 'pdfjs-dist' in Next JS and Typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, next.js, pdfjs-dist

I am trying to use the 'pdfjs-dist' package to extract the text from a pdf file that I retrieve from my AWS S3 bucket. When I call the code I receive the error:

```
Error: Setting up fake worker failed: "Cannot find module './pdf.worker.js'
```

I am confused on what this means, and not too sure on how to resolve it. My code looks like this:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import * as PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist';
import { TextItem } from 'pdfjs-dist/types/src/display/api';

export async function POST(
) {

    let myFiledata = await fetch("url to my S3 bucket")

    if (myFiledata.ok) {
        let pdfDoc = await PDFJS.getDocument(await myFiledata.arrayBuffer()).promise
        const numPages = pdfDoc.numPages
        for (let i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
            let page = await pdfDoc.getPage(i + 1)
            let textContent = await page.getTextContent()
            const text = textContent.items.map((item) => (item as TextItem).str).join('');

            console.log(text)

        }

        return new NextResponse("Success", { status: 200 });
    } else {
      
        return new NextResponse("Internal Error", { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

How do I go about solving this issue? Do I need to add a file somewhere in my project, or is it isolated to the code?

I tried various methods of initializing the pdf.worker.js such by using some variation of:

```
PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc
```

And setting it equal to a various urls such as

```
pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.entry.js;
pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker.entry.entry;
pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.worker
pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js
```

And even using the pdfjs version to call:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfVersion}/pdf.worker.js
```

Each time it says it does not recognize these urls, so either I'm calling it incorrectly, or just way off from the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by moving the pdf.worker.js file which was nested in my node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js to my public folder, copying the path and setting that path in this line of code:

```
PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "copied path to pdf.worker.js"
```